# Snake game board C++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

My goal is to make a snake game.

So I have to make the board first I think, and I made an array for it.  It has two dimensions, x and y. But after it, I don't even know what to do. I can handle the movement. I don't understand how to initialize a board, help me. I am using Code:blocks. 
I am only using console app.

the code is here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int board[50][50];
srand (time(NULL));
int foodX = rand() % 50 + 0;
int foodY = = rand() % 50 + 0;

for (int i; i < 50; i++)
{
  //i don't know well multi-dimension arrays
}

}
```

Comment: Please provide sample code to highlight your progress.

Comment: What specifically don't you understand? Can you demonstrate the with some code you have tried please?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to add code in comments so I edited post

Comment: No reason to add those `0`'s, by the way..

Comment: BTW, there are no physics involved in a typical snake game.  You may want to remove the "game-physics" tag.  The `game-physics` tag is for issues like determining when a ball hits a player or how the ball bounces off a paddle in Pong game.

Comment: thanks, I edited it

Answer (score 0):

The core of the snake game is determining how to position the snake.    There is no real need for a board.

You can represent the board by using maximum horizontal and vertical values.  If the snake hits a border, the game is over.

A common question about the Snake Game is how to position or draw the snake on the screen.  You'll need a platform specific library to do that, like NCurses.  You could use a 2d array of spaces and print the array after each move.

If you are going to use a "board", I highly recommend adding one extra column.  Let the extra column hold a line ending character.  This will allow for easier printing of the board (especially if the last cell is a nul character).

Answer (score 0):

To initialize the board, first use meaningful names.  And only define the constants in one place:

```
#define HEIGHT 50
#define WIDTH 50
int board[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
...    
for (int row; row < HEIGHT; row++)
{
    for (int col; col < WIDTH; col++)
    {
       board[row][col] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it as soon as possible. I think I will use a board with characters to see where are the borders of the game.